# How to Crawl Website Content by Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-crawler

I'm studying Python. I want to get content on one URL  . Get all text in one title  on the website and save it to file .txt. Can you show me some code example?

Comment: Google BeautifulSoup and/or Scrapy. There's lots of code examples out there.

Comment: There are many examples in other questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

By `Get all text in one title on the website` I assume you mean get the title of the page?

Firstly, you'll need BeautifulSoup

If you have `pip`, use

`pip install beautifulsoup4`

Now onto the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
r = get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
title = soup.title.string #I save the title to a variable rather then jus
with open('url.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(title)
```

Now, where ever you have the script saved, will have a file called `url.txt` containing the URL.

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')`, `lxml` works faster than `html.parser`